# The included part ''xclickcounter.dart'' must have a part-of directive

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

Create a sample web application using the Web UI (web_ui) library, e.g., mylib

open mylib.dart, make it a library:

```dart
library mylib;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

part 'xclickcounter.dart';
...
```

open xclickcounter.dart, remove imports and insert:

```dart
part of mylib;
```

`web/out/mylib.dart` and `web/out/xclickcounter.dart` get messed up:

> The included part ''xclickcounter.dart'' must have a part-of directive
>
> Classes can only mixin other classes
>
> Mixin can only be applied to class
>
> ... more errors follow

What am I doing wrong?  Please help :(

---

Edit:  if I don't edit generated sample code, wdc will generate code that falls into separate libraries:

- web/out/xclickcounter.dart => x_click_counter
- web/out/mylib.dart => mylib_html

Does it mean that if we use web_ui we should not create our own libraries and wdc will do this for us automatically?

---

Update: if I don't use any library name, similar to what generated sample code does, and only rely on the library names generated by xdc in web/out/... files, I still run into trouble when importing my two components into a 3rd file.  Dart Editor will produce the following warning:

> The imported libraries 'compa.dart' and 'compb.dart'
> should not have the same   name

The workaround is to name your libraries based on what xdc produces in web/out/... files, that is:

- compa.dart => x-comp-a
- compb.dart => x-comp-b

After explicitly placing components into libraries like these the Dart Editor warning disappears.